# How to insert,update records from execute sql task in ssis without using any transformation?

Tags: ssis-2012, msbi

we have oledbCommand Transformation for Update,delete pupose in SSIS it works fine but it will reduce the performance when we have huge amount of data so we can write a query in execute sql task in control flow pane in ssis for insert,update record i know this works but i don't know how to do so guys please help me.

Comment: Please be more specific - your current question is too broad. You may omit 'give me a proper answer'.

Comment: Usually we use oledbCommand transformation for update table but same thing we can do from the query in execute sql task in control flow pane in SSIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can achieve this in two ways using execute sql task.
1.Insert data into global temporary table,then use execute sql task update your target table with join temporary table and can also insert data to your target table using temporary table.
2. Insert data into in dummy table(database) then update and insert target table using this dummy table. You can use merge statement for insert and update.
```

Comment: Awesome right answer thank you some guys without knowing question they just simply give minus marks rudolf_franek